# TableView Scrollbar size

Tags: javafx-2

I'm using css to change the default font size of TableView controls.
My problem is that when the font size is changed also changes the scrollbar width (it looks thinner as the font size is decreased).

I'd like to change the TableView's font size maintaining the default scrollbar width.

My css file:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This is http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20922

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution styling the table rows only, instead of the whole tableview.

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an issue on that http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20922

You could try specify -fx-font-size for the scroll bar directly in the css like this:

```
.table-view > .virtual-flow > .scroll-bar {
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
}
```

You could also refer to caspian.css inside jfxrt.jar to see other possible solutions.

Comment: It doesn't worked for me, but thanks to the suggestion I found an alternative solution in caspian.css

Comment: In 2021 (JavaFX 16, JDK 17 on OSX), this worked for vertical and horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button, 
.table-view .scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button {
    -fx-padding: 0.5em 0.5em  ;
}
```

This can help with the scrollbar width, make it wider.